# MassTransit with MQTT transport

Tags: masstransit

Is there a way to use MQTT as a transport in MassTransit?

I would kike to use MQTT instead of RabbitMQ, because the latter requires a bit more complicated install process, and an app using RabbitMQ as a transport would be difficult to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit does not support MQTT, the supported transports include:

- RabbitMQ
- Azure Service Bus
- ActiveMQ (Amazon MQ)
- Amazon SQS

There are no plans to support MQTT at this time or in the foreseeable future.